# Angular2-SpringBoot application : "Authorization" request header overridden by SpringBoot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

"Authorization" request header sent from angular2 has value as "Bearer" but when it reaches filter of SpringBoot it shows value as "Basic".
Is Spring security overriding it?
**Angular2 code :**

```
 getGreeting(): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authenticationService.token });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2))
    +"/rest/hello",options).map(res => res.text())
}
```

Filter Code:
    @Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

```
    if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/rest/")) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith(Constants.BEARER)) {
            throw new ServletException(Constants.MISSING_HEADER);
        }
```

Comment: Is it the same request?

Comment: Yes. I am able to get other headers.

Comment: headers aren't immutable, so you can't control them.